# raml 0.8 enum values and multiple selection in example

Tags: raml

I am using RAML 0.8 and I am defining a query string parameter.

the value for the querystring should be a comma separated list of predefined values

So I have used enum to define the list of acceptable values to use

```
sort:
  description: Comma separated list of stock item properties to sort on.
  enum: ['status', 'orderType', 'stockType', 'model', orderNumber']
  example: 'orderType,status'
```

However with the example, I am getting this warning

value should be one of 'status', 'orderType', 'stockType', 'model', 'orderNumber'

I would prefer if possible to get rid of this warning for the example. With RAML 0.8 is this even possible, or should I just ignore it as its only a warning and not an error

Answer (score 0):

The warning is valid. An enum type will only expect one of the possible value. If you need to send an array of those values like: ?sort=status,orderType Then you will need to use a pattern. The example below uses regex to allow a comma seperate list of values. And the specific enum values that can be used are in the pattern.

```
#%RAML 0.8

title: enum-list

version: v1
protocols: [ HTTP ]
mediaType: application/json

traits:
  sortable:
    queryParameters:
      sort?:
        type: string
        pattern: ^(\s?[<<fieldset>>,]+\s?,)*(\s?[<<fieldset>>,]+)$
        example: 'status,orderType'
/api:
  displayName: api
  get:
   is: [ sortable: { fieldset: status|orderType|stockType|model|orderNumber } ]
```